# Question about FMDB and JOIN clause

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, fmdb

I'm using FMDB as the sqlite wrapper, which is pretty easy to get onto.
I encountered the problem when I try to join two (in fact one) table.

To distinguish the joined two table's columns, I have to use `select a.a as 'a.a', b.a as 'b.a' from the_table as a join the_table as b on...`. Then I can use `[rs stringForColumn:@"a.a"]` and `[rs stringForColumn:@"b.a"]` to access them (Where rs is of class FMResultSet). But I have about 15 columns so the sql string seems really long. I'm wondering if there's any easier way to do this?

Using `select * from the_table as a join the_table as b...`, can I access the content of a and b separately? May something like `[rs resultSetForRenamedTable:@"a"]`;

Answer (score 1):

Well, FMDB is just a wrapper on top of SQLite,

I suppose SQLite will fire an error if you use ***** in this particular case. Something like: *SQL error: ambiguous column name: a*

Comment: If I use *, there's no error or warning related to ambiguous column name, because I have not specified column names. Then I can get values by index, but I don't know how to get `a.a` and `b.a`.

Answer (score 0):

Use ATTACH DATABASE query https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html

For example:

```
db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:mCoreDatabase]; 
[db open]; 
NSString *attachSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"ATTACH DATABASE '%@' AS db2", yourDB2Path]; 
[db executeUpdate:attachSQL];
```